# Simple Model Binding Not Working For Integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model-binding

I'm trying to figure out why this simple controller action isn't working. All I'm trying to do is increase `Number` after every POST.

**Model**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
}
```

**View**

```
<body>

    <% using (Html.BeginForm("Test", "Invoice"))
    { %>
        <%: Html.EditorFor(m => m.Number) %>
        <%= Model.Number %>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    <% } %>

</body>
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
   var viewModel = new ViewModel {Number = 1};
   return View("Test", viewModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Number = viewModel.Number + 1;
    return View("Test", viewModel);
}
```

In my controller, `viewModel.Number` is increased to `2`, but when the view is returned the text box contains `1` and `Model.Number` displays 2.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Html helpers favor the values in the `ModelState` over the actual Model values.

So if you modify the Model in your action you need to clear the `ModelSate` before passing it to the view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    viewModel.Number = viewModel.Number + 1;
    ModelState.Clear();
    return View("Test", viewModel);
}
```

You can read more about this ASP.NET MVC feature in this great article:

[ASP.NET MVC Postbacks and HtmlHelper Controls ignoring Model Changes](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Apr/20/ASPNET-MVC-Postbacks-and-HtmlHelper-Controls-ignoring-Model-Changes)

Comment: Thanks so much - I knew it had to be something minor. Great article for reference also.